# "In Unicode programs, must have the same structure layout, irrespective of the length" error

Tags: unicode, abap

I'm now getting this error after making a small mod to a working program. The structures have the same type (though the tables are different) but I get this error? I've looked at similar postings but couldn't find an answer to this.
Codes snippets included.

```
* ---
    ,begin of TY_RESB_CDC
      ,MANDT                  type MANDT        
      ,RSNUM                  type RSNUM
      ,RSPOS                  type RSPOS
      ,RSART                  type RSART
      ,UDATE                  type CDDATUM
      ,UTIME                  type CDUZEIT
      .include                type ZBW_MATERIAL_RESVN_RESB.
 types: end of TY_RESB_CDC
        ,TT_RESB_CDC              type hashed table of TY_RESB_CDC
                                  with unique key RSNUM  RSPOS  RSART
        ,TT_RESB_STD              type standard table of TY_RESB_CDC
                                  with empty key
    ---
   ,LT_RESB_CDC               type TT_RESB_CDC
   ,WA_RESB_CDC               type TY_RESB_CDC    "like LINE OF LT_RESB_CDC
   ,LT_RESB_STD               type TT_RESB_STD
   ,WA_RESB_STD               type TY_RESB_CDC    "like line of LT_RESB_STD
---

      move-corresponding <FS_DATA>    to WA_RESB_STD.
     " already exists in CDC
      if  WA_RESB_STD eq WA_RESB_CDC. "<FS_RESB_CDC>.
        continue.   "no change, skip this record
```

Answer (score 4):

A component name cannot contain a dot in its name, in a Unicode program. Same for any other ABAP symbolic name.

The below code with name `.include` is not permitted. You were mistaken by DDIC structures, which have different rules.

```
TYPES: begin of TY_RESB_CDC,
         ...
         UTIME      type CDUZEIT,
         .include   type ZBW_MATERIAL_RESVN_RESB,
       end of TY_RESB_CDC.
```

Instead, you should use the ABAP statement [`INCLUDE TYPE`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abapinclude_type.htm) to include the components of a structure (e.g. `ZBW_MATERIAL_RESVN_RESB` in your case):

```
TYPES: begin of TY_RESB_CDC,
         ...
         UTIME      type CDUZEIT.
INCLUDE TYPE ZBW_MATERIAL_RESVN_RESB.
TYPES: end of TY_RESB_CDC.
```